# Meaning of "because p is a mean not a total" in the derivation of the standard error of p

Tags: self-study, distributions

From **onlinestatbook**'s section on "[Sampling distribution of p](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/sampling_distributions/samp_dist_p.html)":

> [image]

I don't understand this phrase. If p had been "a total" (if the entirety of the population were sampled?) we would have divided the formula by something other than N?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first standard deviation refers to the count (an integer): The number of successes (say M) out of N trials with a success probability of $\pi$. Most of the times the number of successes M is not of interest but rather the fraction of successes $\hat{p}=\frac{M}{N}$. You can easily figure out yourself why you would divide by N then.